# Some custom icons are shown only in sudo mode

Tags: nautilus, sudo, icons, themes

Some icons from [Zafiro icons theme](https://github.com/zayronxio/Zafiro-icons/tree/master/mimetypes/48) are only shown when I use Nautilus in root mode (sudo nautilus) but aren't shown in normal mode.

Normal mode:
[image]

Root mode:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT run nautilus as root!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your user may not have read permissions for the custom icon files.

Make sure the path to any custom icon has read permissions.

To set permissions to rw-r--r-- on the icon files so that the owner can read and write, and all other users can read the file, open a terminal and run:

`chmod 644 /path/to/iconfile`

If your user does not own the file, you will need to run the command under sudo:

`sudo chmod 644 /path/to/iconfile`